# Rails 2.3.8 named_scope chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have the following nested if statement hairball, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing this code (less lines of code that doesn't require so many conditionals)

Each of the methods are named_scopes within the model..

```
box = (params[:b] ? params[:b] : "inbox")
show = (params[:s] ? params[:s] : "all")

if box == "inbox"
  if show == "all"
    @messages = @current_user.received_messages.all  
  elsif show == "unread"
    @messages = @current_user.received_messages.unread.all  
  elsif show == "read"
    @messages = @current_user.received_messages.read.all  
  elsif show == "starred"
    @messages = @current_user.received_messages.starred.all  
  else
    @messages = []
  end
elsif box = "sent"
  @messages = @current_user.sent_messages.all  
else
  @messages = []
end
```

My thought was that I could use a 'call' type of method for box and show like

```
@current_user.received_messages.call(:box).call(:show).all
```

maybe..?

UGH, should have spent a bit more time playing around.. its just as i thought, I was just using the wrong method **SOLUTION**

```
@current_user.send(box).send(show)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `scoped()` method in rails 2.3.8 to chain scopes:

```
main_method = case (params[:s]||"inbox")
when "inbox"
  :received_messages
when "sent"
  :sent_messages
end
# create a scope. Don't execute the scope yet. 
scope = @current_user.send(main_method).scoped({}) if main_method

# now chain the scope if needed
scope = begin
  if ["unread", "read", "starred"].include?(params[:s])
    scope.send(params[:s])
  elsif((params[:s] || "all") == "all")
    scope
  end
end if main_method == :received_messages

@messages = scope.nil? ? [] : scope.all
```

**Reference:**

[Scoped method source in Rails 2.3.x](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L19)

[Rails casts on Anonymous scopes in 2.3.x](http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes)

Comment: I didn't know about the scoped method, is this basically the step before arel magic in rails 3? So i can create queries and then run it after all conditions have been attached?

Comment: I have added some references to the method. Watch the Railscast specified for more information.

Comment: Awesome thank you! This an addition to rails 2.3.9? not available in 2.3.8?

Comment: It is available in 2.3.x also.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured out, I'm not going to mark my own answer as correct unless everyone agrees this is the best - ***any other ideas?***

```
if params[:b].present? && ["received_messages", "sent_messages"].include?(params[:b])
  box = params[:b]

  if params[:s].present? && ["all", "unread", "starred"].include?(params[:s])
    show = params[:s]
  else
    show = "all"
  end

  @messages = @current_user.send(box).send(show)
else
  @messages = []
end
```

Comment: Please do `box = params[:b:] || "received_messages"` rather than a ternary statement.

Comment: i just changed it actually, since i have the .include?() I don't need the || at all..

Comment: you don't need to check the presence of a param if you already check its inclusion in an array.  It will check for the inclusion of `nil` which will return `false`, when not present.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is very close but it fails to convert `box` values.

```
box  = params[:b] || 'inbox'
show = params[:s] || 'all'

box_scope = case box
  when 'inbox' then 'received_messages'
  when 'sent'  then 'sent_messages'
end
show_scope = show # no convertion needed at this point, maybe in the future

# If box_scope is nil, don't query
@messages = box_scope.nil? ? [] : @current_user.send(box_scope).send(show_scope)
```

This assumes you do away with the `.all` you were using in the original code for *all* options, which disappeared in your answer.

Comment: Makes me wonder what would happen if `sent` box is selected with any *show* option other than `all`.

Comment: yea, i actually ended up changing the link so that :b comes in as received and sent messages but I like the box_scope = case gig you have going on there haha, thanks! QUESTION: How would box_scope end up as nil? wouldnt it be undefined if an unknown value came in?

Comment: right, we want to make sure that its one of the filter options, otherwise just show "all"

Comment: @Rabbott, in Ruby, all `case` and `if` blocks return `nil` when none of the conditions match.